# Writing boolean expression in unix scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Hi Can anyone help me in writing the expression with boolean form, right now am not able to execute it.Here stat_1 and stat_2 are two empty string

My best effort is:

```
[ [ "$stat_1" -a "$stat_2" ] &&  [ $stat_1 -eq 5 -a $stat_2 -eq 0 ] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to test that `stat_1` equals 5, and `stat_2` equals 0.

This can simply be accomplished this way :

```
[ "$stat_1" = 5 ] && [ "$stat_2" = 0 ]
```

You could perform the tests in a single bracket with `-a`, but I find it cleaner using two sets of bracketed expressions with a single test in each.

It would be preferable to keep your variables inside quotes, or else you may have unwanted results if they contain spaces (which would expand to additional arguments inside the brackets).

If you are using bash, you have access to double bracketed conditionals :

```
[[ "$stat_1" = 5 ]] && [[ "$stat_2" = 0 ]]
```

These do the same job, but they are built into the shell, and offer some additional functionality, especially pattern matching `=~` which I use constantly.

Comment: Hi @Fred my condition is :
In what cases wukk $instr_type and $instr_subtype be undefined - fake spns?

We should combine both of these if statements into one block.

Also, this should be a single invocation of test rather than four, with the -a switch used for the and operator instead of bash's &&. I think:

if [ $var2 -a $var1 -a $var2 -eq 5 -a $var1 -eq 0 ]; then

Comment: @Fred With double brackets you can use `[[1 == 1 && 2 == 2]]`.

Comment: @AnitaPandey : I prefer having several invocations (which are very light given a shell built-in is used, not an external program) instead of a complicated conditional (easier to understand and debug), but that is matter of preference ; you should quote your variables though, unless you are really, really sure they contain only digits.